# RpcDispatcher#callRemoteMethods does not work while calling MembershipListener#viewAccepted when using ForkChannel

Tags: java, jgroups

RpcDispatcher#callRemoteMethods does not work while calling MembershipListener#viewAccepted when using ForkChannel.

I am trying to upgrade the version of JGroups used in my application from 2 to 4.1.0.Final.
The application uses MuxRpcDispatcher because it uses multiple RpcDispatchers.
The mux package has been deprecated in version 4 and we are trying to use an alternative fork-stack.
However, when you execute RpcDispatcher in viewAccepted, processing freeze.

RpcDispatcher#callRemoteMethods does not work while calling MembershipListener#viewAccepted when using ForkChannel.

```java
channel = new JChannel();
channel.setReceiver(this);

if (channel.getProtocolStack().findProtocol(FORK.class) == null) {
    channel.getProtocolStack().addProtocol(new FORK());
}

forkChannel = new ForkChannel(channel, "fork", "fork");
dispatcher1 = new RpcDispatcher(forkChannel, new Boe1());

channel.connect("test");
forkChannel.connect("test");
```

Calling RpcDispatcher in viewAccepted. Processing stops on this call.

```java
@Override
public void viewAccepted(final View new_view) {
    LOGGER.info("viewAccepted:start");
    try {
        final MethodCall call = new MethodCall(Boe1.class.getMethod("boeee"));
        final RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions(ResponseMode.GET_ALL, 0, true, null);
        dispatcher1.callRemoteMethods(null, call, options);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOGGER.info("viewAccepted:end");
}
```

The following is a thread dump in the stopped state.

```
"jgroups-10,test,IM9072-10017" #22 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002b4b5800 nid=0x2cf8 waiting on condition [0x000000002c84d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000071b24ccd0> (a java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1693)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3323)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(CompletableFuture.java:1729)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.GroupRequest.access$7(GroupRequest.java:1)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.GroupRequest$$Lambda$135/1688803174.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.GroupRequest.doAndComplete(GroupRequest.java:274)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.GroupRequest.waitForCompletion(GroupRequest.java:254)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.GroupRequest.waitForCompletion(GroupRequest.java:1)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.Request.execute(Request.java:52)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher.cast(MessageDispatcher.java:319)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher.castMessage(MessageDispatcher.java:251)
    at org.jgroups.blocks.RpcDispatcher.callRemoteMethods(RpcDispatcher.java:96)
    at ppp.network.JChannelRunner.viewAccepted(JChannelRunner.java:79)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.invokeCallback(JChannel.java:917)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:759)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:908)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FORK.up(FORK.java:131)
```

Is there a way to avoid freezes?

Comment: The minimal source to reproduce the event is:

https://pastebin.com/burV7gZT

Occurs when this Java application is launched in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* block in a callback, such as `viewAccepted()`! If you absolutely *have* to invoke an RPC, either invoke it asynchronously (mode=`GET_NONE`), or out-of-band (`OOB`).
You could also do this in a separate thread.

See [1] for details.
Cheers,

[1] http://www.jgroups.org/manual4/index.html#ReceiverAdapter

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

It will also freeze if you invoke PRC with the out-of-band flag set.
Even if it is another thread, it will freeze if you make an RPC call immediately after viewAccepted is called.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you made is that you registered a view listener on the JChannel, but *not* on the ForkChannel.

This means the `viewAccepted()` callback got invoked when the ForkChannel didn't yet have a view, so invoking the method would return immediately as no membership had been recorded at that point.

I commented that line and added dispatcher1.setMembershipListener(), and now, the sample code works.
Cheers,

```
public class JChannelRunner extends ReceiverAdapter implements Closeable {
    public static class Boe1 {
        public void boeee() {System.out.println("boe-1");}
    }

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JChannelRunner.class.getName());

    JChannel channel;
    ForkChannel forkChannel;
    RpcDispatcher dispatcher1;

    protected void start() throws Exception {
        channel = new JChannel();
        // channel.setReceiver(this);

        if (channel.getProtocolStack().findProtocol(FORK.class) == null) {
            channel.getProtocolStack().addProtocol(new FORK());
        }

        forkChannel = new ForkChannel(channel, "fork", "fork");
        dispatcher1 = new RpcDispatcher(forkChannel, new Boe1());
        dispatcher1.setMembershipListener(this);
        channel.connect("test");
        forkChannel.connect("test");
    }

    public JChannelRunner() throws Exception {}

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        try (JChannelRunner runner = new JChannelRunner()) {
            runner.start();
            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        Util.close(dispatcher1, forkChannel, channel);
    }

    @Override
    public void viewAccepted(final View new_view) {
        LOGGER.info("viewAccepted:start");
        try {
            final MethodCall call = new MethodCall(Boe1.class.getMethod("boeee"));
            final RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions(ResponseMode.GET_ALL, 0, true, null);
            dispatcher1.callRemoteMethods(null, call, options);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LOGGER.info("viewAccepted:end");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I tried verifying with the provided source code, but unfortunately I got the same result as before.
(When we checked the thread dump, freeze occurred at the same point as before)

Comment: Works for me! Did you run the above program unchanged? If the issue still occurs, please open a JIRA issue for JGroups (JGRP) and attach the program you used, plus logs for org.jgroups at TRACE level.